# Excel Worksheet_change event no longer firing

Tags: events, excel-2016

I dont know when this stopped working to be frank but not long switched to using Office 2016. Either way now a VBA event that previously was firing is not now doing so. At least it does not stop at the first position in the sub where I can set a breakpoint.

There is no use of EnableEvents in this project or other open project, and where the event previously fired, the process reformatting the active cell and another, now it does nothing.

Any help most appreciated!

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Const STATUSCOL1 = "L"
Const STATUSCOL2 = "M"
Const STATUSCOL3 = "N"
Const STATUSCOL4 = "O"
Const STATUSCOL5 = "P"
Const STATUSCOL6 = "Q"
Const STATUSCOL7 = "R"
Const STATUSCOL8 = "S"
Const ACTIONCOL1 = "NOT IMPLEMENTED"


    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim ac As String
    Dim rgtCellVal As Integer

    Set Cell = Target
    ac = Split(Cell.Address, "$")(1) 'For Column Letter

    'if any changes at all mark colum J in Green
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        'If Cell <> IIf(vOldData = vbNullString, "(Null)", vOldData) Then
        If Cell.Value <> vOldData Then
            Select Case ac
                Case ACTIONCOL1
                    Cells(Cell.Row, Range("J" & 1).Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 42 'Aqua
                Case Else
                    Cells(Cell.Row, Range("J" & 1).Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'bright green
            End Select
        End If

    End If


    'Status
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Installed & Active
    'I&A with Bugs
    'Compromise
    'If Required
    'NotActivatedOrUsed
    'UserBlogUseOnly
    'UpdateHold
    '------------------------------------------
    'Deactivated
    'Depricated
    'Removed
    'Not Installed
    '------------------------------------------
    'Failed
    'Broken but activated
    'Broken and deactivated
    '------------------------------------------
    'Status in question
    'Ignore
    'N.A.
    'Not Actionable
    'In Progress
    'Review
    'ConsiderNew
    If ac = STATUSCOL1 Or ac = STATUSCOL2 Or ac = STATUSCOL3 Or ac = STATUSCOL4 Or ac = STATUSCOL5 Or ac = STATUSCOL6 Or ac = STATUSCOL7 Or ac = STATUSCOL8 Then

        Select Case Cell
            Case ""
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone 'none

            Case "Installed & Active"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 43 'Lime

            Case "I&A with Bugs"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36 'Light Yellow

            Case "Compromise"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 35 'Light Green

            Case "If Required"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 'Grey - 25%

             Case "UserBlogUseOnly"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 'Grey - 25%

            Case "UpdateHold"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 46 'Orange

            '------------------------------------------
            Case "NotActivatedOrUsed"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 'Grey - 25%

            Case "Deactivated"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 'Grey - 25%

            Case "Depricated"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'pale blue
            Case "Removed"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 41 'Light blue
            Case "Rejected"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 41 'Light blue
            Case "Not Installed"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'pale blue

            '------------------------------------------
            Case "Failed"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Red
            Case "Broken"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Red
            Case "BrokenButDeactivated"

                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'pale blue
            '------------------------------------------

            Case "StatusInQuestion"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 44 'Gold

            Case "Ignore"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone 'none

            Case "N.A."
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone 'none

            Case "Not Actionable"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone 'none

            Case "In Progress"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 'Grey - 25%

            Case "Review"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 33 'Sky Blue

            Case "ConsiderAlt"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 44 'Gold

            Case "------------------------------------------"
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone 'none


            Case Else
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 40 'Tan

                rgtCellVal = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
                If (Cell = "") And rgtCellVal = 15 Then
                    Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                End If
        End Select

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not trying to be one of "those" guys, but why don't you just use conditional formatting?  Does any VB code run?  are the Macros or workbook Disabled?

Comment: Well it could be that the number of rules that you can have with conditional formatiing has changed but previously I think there was a limit of three. If a greater number is now available making this viable, it might certainly be an easier option ongoing. However it could also be that something simple requires a changed methodology. Hence the question. Also I dont want to create 24 rules for the sake of it if ther is a simple fix for something broken with a workaround.

Comment: On your other questions @Profex I hadnt realised this but only one other event has code "Worksheet_SelectionChange" and ineed this is also not firing. How would I have disable VBA or are you saying I would need to enable it under excel 2016? i.e disabled by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Excel 2016 yet, but in 2007-2013 you can check macro setting under

**File** `-->` **Options** `-->` **Trust Center** `-->` **Trust Center Settings...** `-->` **Macro Settings**

Make sure that *Disable all macros with notification* or better is selected

If it was an Add-In, I'd say check to the disabled Add-In's, but it doesn't look like one.

Where is the file located? If it's on a network drive does it work when you copy it to a local drive?
If so then, the check the **Trusted Documents** options under the **Trust Center Settings...**

Comment: VBA is not the same as a Macro. There are no Add-Ins involved. there is no external file, unless you mean the Access file itself.

Comment: In Excel, Macros=VBA.  Did I miss where you said anything about Access?

Comment: Indeed sorry Typo I should have said Excel! And I must confess coming from a primarily Access background (hence the slip) I hadnt relaised that in excel rthey were one and the same!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have the answer:
Trust Center. Macro Settings tab. Developer Macro Settings section. Trust Access to the VBA project object model. Tick Yes!

Comment: That setting allows you to change the VBA code via code.  i.e. I can write a virus that adds VBA code to any excel document you have, or delete all of your VBA code.  I'm glad you found the setting that worked, but be careful with that setting.